# how to run cronjob for a python script in a virtual env that has request lib to make curl req?

Tags: python, curl, cron, python-requests, virtualenv

I have a python script that uses the requests lib to make curl request to a url and get the response. When i run it manually, it is able to get the response object and update the var value. There is virtual env set for the script as well. Script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
source myEnv/bin/activate
python /Users/mj/req.py
```

and the crontab is as follows:

```
*/1 * * * *  /Users/mj/Enviroments/myscript.sh >> /Users/mj/Enviroments/myout.txt
```

and req.py:

```
resp = requests.post(<some url>)
print(resp.json())
```

And to run the script:

```
source myscript.sh
```

It prints the resp obj and also activates the virtual env but output is not reflected in myout.txt.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but can't you make `req.py` write the `json`object directly to  `myout.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of activating the environment try using the full path to the python that is inside that virtual env:

Change this:

```
#! /bin/bash
source myEnv/bin/activate
python /Users/mj/req.py
```

To something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
/.../myEnv/bin/python /Users/mj/req.py
```